# HTML element disappears while scrolling page with video

Tags: html, google-chrome, video, element

Scrolling HTML page which has video element makes other overlapping HTML elements with higher z-index disappeared.
This issue occurs in Chrome but not in Firefox.
How to fix it?

Example: ("Full page" recommended)

```css
video{height: 500px; z-index: 1; }
div
{
  width: 300px; height: 600px;
  background: red; position: relative;
  z-index: 2; top: -300px; left: 200px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <video src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" loop autoplay muted></video>
  
    <div id="d1">It disappears on scroll</div>
  
  
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
</body>
</html>
```

Sometimes it doesn't disappear but after refreshing page it disappears.

Comment: I'm using google chrome and I didn't see any change in the div.

Comment: would you mind putting the *source* code in your answer

Comment: Random Channel: I have tested my issue on other computer with other OS and new installed Google Chrome. HTML element still disappears as i said.

Comment: take the entire code, and paste it into a solution, then delete it once I say I got the code copied.

Comment: I don't have any solution for this, but I can confirm this is an issue for us and our client in Google Chrome (latest version as of this comment). We usually see that it makes stuff disappear when scrolled past 60% of the video (only bottom 40% left visible).

It is all very intermittent, and no absolutes in reproducibility.

Comment: There are many websites with video and content on it. They know solution for this bug. Anyway I will try to find out how to fix it and post solution in future. For now Chrome has version: 66.0.3359.181 and this issue appears.

Answer (score 2):

Thats how i fix it i just used

```
transform: translate3d(20px, -286px, 200px);
```

i defined x, y, z and by this way its avoided the disappearing problem

```css
body { height: 2000px }

video {
  height: 500px; 
  z-index: 15; 
  position: relative;
}

div{
  width: 300px; 
  height: 600px;
  background: red; 
  position: relative;
  z-index: 16;
  transform: translate3d(20px, -286px, 200px);
}
```

```html
<main>
    <video src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" loop autoplay muted></video>
  
    <div id="d1">It disappears on scroll</div>
</main>
```

Comment: These properties work as well:
transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
transform: rotateX(0deg);
transform: rotateY(0deg);

This is short fix for this bug but many websites with elements on video don't use it.